# How to enlarge one image in list view?

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing windows phone App.
For this app I created One page for photos and all photos coming from Facebook.
Problem: Here I want to show first image in first row with bigger size and all other images in next lines with small icon size.
how to do this?

Comment: In XAML view, can you not specify the height and the width of the Image Control? It would be much easier for us to digest the problem if you also provided some code so we can see what you currently have.

Comment: image is comming dynamically so how to mention height?